# Firefox not displaying SVG

Tags: firefox, svg, opera

I have a page that uses SVG to make an image map.

Works fine in IE9 and Chrome but FireFox and Opera are cropping the images - though rollovers do still work.

The site is here: http://www.kollegetown.com

Anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Paste some code please. Last time I check, it works.

Comment: Do what Erik says.  What's happening is that the SVG spec got clarified in terms of how sizing works for `<svg>` elements and Firefox has implemented the clarification while IE9 and Chrome haven't yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this (or something equivalent) to your stylesheet:

```
svg { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```